# Fastest way to determine if a conic section is an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

Given an arbitrary conic section in the form
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey +F=0$$
(Where the coefficients are real valued)
is there a simple test which can determine whether or not a particular conic is an ellipse? I know that if a conic section is an ellipse, then $A$ and $C$ will have the same sign, however I am not sure if this is a sufficient condition as well.

Edit: Forgot to include the "$...+F=0$".

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee from the link it says to evaluate $B^2 - 4AC$ - do I need to rotate the conic section first though?

Comment: Just check if $B^2-4AC<0$

Comment: No, the quantity $B^2-4AC$ is invariant under rotations. You might want to check this: it’s messy, but very satisfying to come out with the result.

Comment: Your ellipse necessarily passes through the origin?

Comment: @Bernard No, and what do you mean by "passes through"?

Comment: The origin is a point of the ellipse. This is the case if there's no constant term in the equation.

Comment: Ah, with the conics I have, this is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer for the normalised equation of a non-degenerate conic
$$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+T=0.$$

Consider the matrix 
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & D \\ B & C &E \\ D &E & F
\end{bmatrix} $$
and the matrix of the quadratic part of the equation
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ B & C
\end{bmatrix}. $$
The conic is non-degenerate if and only if $\det M\ne 0$.  Further, the conic is an ellipse if and only if:

1. The quadratic part of the equation (associated to the matrix $Q$) has signature $(2,0)$;
2. The quadratic form on $\mathbf R^3$ associated to $M$ has signature $(2,1)$.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using this method over checking $B^2 - 4AC$? Does checking $B^2 - 4AC$ only work if it "passes through the origin"?

Comment: The sign $B^2-4AC$ tests the possibility of points at infinity, i.e. the possibility of a hyperbola (2 points at infinity) or a parabola (az double  ipoint at infinity. It's equivalent to the signature of $A$, but there may be degenerate cases which are handled by the study of  the matrix $M$. In the ellipse case, the curve  may be empty or reduced to a point.

Answer (score 1):

If  $ I_2=B^2-4AC$ is negative then it is an ellipse whether or not (RHS being  zero ) it passes  through origin as special case.